# Where is the source code for Java Type Promotion and how to debug it

Tags: java, casting, jvm, double, type-promotion

I basically want to debug the following code for Type Promotion to understand the temporary double variable created for x. How can I do this?

```
public class TypePromotion {
public static void main(String args[]){
    int x = 10;
    double y = 20.0;
    double z = x + y;

    System.out.println("value of Z is :: "+z); // outputs 30.0
    System.out.println("value of X is :: "+x); // outputs 10
}}
```

Comment: Request you guys to downvote if you already know the answer and think it's too trivial :-) Also please suggest where should i post it

Comment: Where is the source code for TypePromotion ... you just shared it. this question seems nonsense at best, I'm afraid

Comment: We are uncertain what your "source code" or "debug" means. Please tell us what exactly you want to acheive. Um, look, you want to "debug", but what is the "bug" you are looking for? You want the source code, but you have already presented the "source code" (albeit in a poor format).

Comment: :-) by source code I mean JDK or JVM level source code where the Type Promotion actually happens. This is an example of Type Promotion, not its source code. 
and by debugging I mean to debug the line z = x+y to reach the jdk or jvm source code

Comment: the temp double created for x is done at runtime inside the JRE. this is platform-specific and there are many JRE implementations

Comment: @VikramSinghChandel there is no 'JDK or JVM level source code' of what you code yourself.

Comment: `javac` compiles your source file (`TypePromotion.java`) into _bytecode_, which is similar to but not the same as assembler (JVMS has a section on what instruction do what). In order to look at what bytecode `javac` has emitted, you should use `javap`. The use of `javap` is trival as long as you have read its help message.

Comment: so if i understood correct, it happens at the syntax analyzer stage of compilation and an extra set of instructions are added for jvm for type promotion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question (as I understand it) is in the Java Language Specification,

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.2

When you use an operator (in this case +) on a pair of operands (x and y) the resulting numeric type is determined by these definitions.

To add a bit more detail, if you disassemble the classfile generated by your code, the relevant instructions are:

```
   0: bipush        10
   2: istore_1
   3: ldc2_w        #2                  // double 20.0d
   6: dstore_2
   7: iload_1
   8: i2d
   9: dload_2
  10: dadd
  11: dstore        4
```

As you can see, x is stored as an int, y is stored as a double.  x is pushed onto the stack then converted to a double.  After y is pushed onto the stack a dadd (double add) can be performed as both operands are doubles.  The javac compiler generates the code that conforms to the Java language spec, as detailed above.

Comment: In short, the conversion occurs with `i2d` +1

Comment: Thanks a lot @Speakjava this is what i was looking for